# sql select with null values

Tags: sql, null

I have SP that selects data from a table with two columns like this

```
@param1 text,
@param2 text
Select * from tablle1 where field1 like @param1 and field2 like @param2
```

However , because sometimes Filed2 is null i had to do this , otherwise the query returned nothing

```
@param1 text,
@param2 text
Select * from tablle1 where field1 like @param1 and (field2 like @param2 OR field2 IS NULL)
```

My problem is that if I now try to run the SP with a value for `@param2` and '%' for `@param1` i get all the rows from the table

How can i make this in every situation ?
I intend to use this SP in a search form on a asp.net site, and give the users the option to use '%' in searches.(eventually there would me more fields to search for and each one will have a textbox on the page that defaults to '%')

Comment: Why oh why do you make a key nullable?

Comment: i didn't say anywhere that it is a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@param1 text,
@param2 text
Select * from tablle1 where field1 like @param1 and isnull(field2,@param2) like @param2 
or
Select * from tablle1 where field1 like @param1 and isnull(field2,'') like @param2
```

Comment: the problem i have with this method is that filed2 is numeric while the @param2 is text (for allowing to pass '%'). I get a text is incompatible with numeric error.

Comment: @Iulian- than first cast your field to varchar by using Cast or Convert function

Comment: i've change it to `Select * from tablle1 where field1 like @param1 and isnull(field2,0) like @param2` and it's working, from my understanding this will make the second condition like `0 = @param2` if the filed2 is empty ?

Comment: @Iulian -try it out may this will work because there is no syntax error

Comment: Yeah it is indeed working , I'm not sure i really understand why :) Is it because the `0 = @param2` will not have any effect on the select ?

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at [Sommarskogs homepage](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

It is the best reference on the subject, and it will also solve some of the other problems you most probably are having with this code.